# Two directives are sharing the same controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Having the following directive

```
function directive() {
    return {
        template: '{{foo.name}}',
        controller: ctrl,
        controllerAs: 'foo'
    }
}

function ctrl($attrs) {
    this.name = $attrs.name;
}
```

and this in a template:

```
<directive name="1" />
<directive name="2" />
```

Why am I seeing the following output:

```
2
2
```

instead of

```
1
2
```

?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The option `controllerAs: 'foo'` does the following:

```
$scope.foo = new ctrl()
```

Your directive doesn't specify the `scope`, that means your directive uses the scope from its parent (`$parentScope`). **In your case, the two directive instances use the same parent scope**. So the two directives:

```
<directive name="1" />
<directive name="2" />
```

Work like:

1. `<directive name="1" />`: `$parentScope.foo = new ctrl()`. Inside the controller: `$parentScope.foo.name = 1`.
2. `<directive name="2" />`: `$parentScope.foo = new ctrl()`. (the instance in step 1 is overwritten). Inside the controller: `$parentScope.foo.name = 2`.

So finally both directives refer to the same `name` defined on the second controller instance.

Solution: use isolate scope as [@Michelem mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32208060/286304).

Comment: good explanation of why isolated scope is needed, not just that it is needed

Answer (score 3):

You have to isolate the scope:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/Lmv32woa/)

```
function directive() {
    return {
        scope: {name: '='},
        template: '{{foo.name}}',
        controller: ctrl,
        controllerAs: 'foo'
    }
}
```

Look at [@Joy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32208276/286304) for explanation

Comment: But how can I use isolated scope when I am using am attribute directive in `input` element? I got the error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir